# Transfer MKV files to iPhone using Airdrop on iOS 13

Tags: iphone, airdrop, encoding

For some time I've beeing using [PlayerXtreme](https://playerxtreme.com/) in order to watch `mkv` videos on my iPhone 8 and I was able to drop them into it from my MBP using **Airdrop**.

But since iOS 13, my iPhone doesn't wants to save `mkv` anymore and claims that I need to download an app to read them:

[image]

Similar to this question : [Transfer MKV files to VLC player on iPhone using Airdrop](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359261/transfer-mkv-files-to-vlc-player-on-iphone-using-airdrop)

How can I save mkv files on my app using **Airdrop** ?

**Note**: I'm still able to save them using USB. I tried with **KMPlayer**, **Infuse**, **VLC** and the issue is the same. I'm on iOS 15.1 & macOS 11.6.1

Since iOS 13.4 I manage to use **Airdrop** to share `avi` & `mp4`, but `mkv` still have the issue

Comment: Which apps get offered when you select the App Store, does it work with any of them? Also, why can't you just "Save to iCloud Drive" to store the video locally on your iDevice and then access it from within your video player?

Comment: No apps get offered when selecting "App Store", only the apps of the day are showing up. If I do "save on icloud drive" the iPhone save the file on files.app and I can then move it to the PlayerXtreme folder -as said below- but I'm worried about why I can't save them directly into the app as before.

Answer (score 2):

It's odd that PlayerXtreme hasn't identified itself as a media player for mkv files.

I just tried it on my phone (iOS13) but I use VLC as my player.

1. Airdrop sent the file ok.
2. On the phone, the received file shows the VLC icon (showing that it recognises the file type).
3. It offers me the option "Open with Files" rather than "Save to iCloud Drive"

On selecting that, it opens the files app and I save the file to the VLC folder under the "On my phone" section of the Files app. The file then shows up in VLC.

"Save to iCloud Drive" is also (since iOS11) done via the Files App, so have you tried simply selecting that and then saving it to PlayerXtreme files location on your phone (if it has one, or a generic folder if not).

Obvious question, but did you update to the latest version of the player since the iOS13 upgrade?

Here's what my receive looks like, with saving to VLC folder in background:

[image: receive MKV via AirDrop iOS13]

Comment: Well, it was like you with vlc when I was on iOS12, but no more... I'm on the latest update of PlayerXtreme, and if I do "save on icloud drive" the iPhone save the file on files.app and  I can then move it to the PlayerXtreme folder... "It's odd that PlayerXtreme hasn't identified itself as a media player for mkv files." is indeed the question...

Comment: I just tried with KMPlayer, Infuse and VLC: same issue...

Comment: Just a thought, do you use one AppleID for iCloud and another for App store?

Comment: No, I only use one AppleID for everything